# Manipulating abstract class as template parameter

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I am trying to implement various sparse matrix formats and manipulate them but I came across a problem which I can't find an answer for.
I have a template class Vector (a math vector) and an abstract template class called Matrix from which all my various matrix formats derive from.
I am trying to create a Vector of Matrix (a tensor) but I can't manage to do so without getting errors. At first, I realised that the following code would not work because a Matrix cannot be instantiated:

```
Vector<Matrix<double>> tensor;
```

So I found out here that putting pointers to Matrices would do the job:

```
Vector<Matrix<double>*> tensor;
```

However, when I try to manipulate it whith polymorphism, I get compilation errors. For example I am trying to code the following function:

```
void foo(Vector<Matrix<double>*> &tensor) {//do something}
```

And I want to be able to use it with a Vector of B, a derived class of Matrix:

```
Vector<B<double>*> b;
foo(b);
```

This gives me the following compilation error:

```
error: could not convert 'b’ from ‘Vector<B<double>*>’ to ‘Vector<Matrix<double>*>’
```

How can I solve this issue?
Thank you for your time !

Comment: [Is a parking-lot-of-Car a kind-of parking-lot-of-Vehicle?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#parkinglot-of-car-vs-vehicle)

Comment: That being said your overall design is questionable... why not make a `template <size_t Dims, class T> struct Tensor {...};` instead and make your actual types by specializing it, e.g. `using VectorF32 = Tensor<1,float>;` `using MatrixUint64 = Tensor<2, uint64_t>`. You wouldn't need inheritance anymore.

Comment: Of course, if it isn't "recreational programming" and you need this to be performant and stable, just use [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) instead.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer and your suggestions!
I was just a bit lazy so I just tried to use the things I already coded to make Tensors. Apparently, it is not possible to do so so I will code it.
I looked into eigen but unfortunately it does not support the formats I want. I need things a bit more sophisticated for what I want to do